# html validator (facebook - google - twitter)

Tags: html, validation

I am validating the following page : -removed
 and I got 13 errors

Those 13 errors are from the facebook and twitter scripts on my site ... I want to remove those 13 errors ! any suggestion?
here is the validation link :
-removed

Comment: You are validating your page with the transitional 1.0 doctype. you should know that facebook use html tag and attributes which are not allowed in this doctype. try to change the doctype validator and also you might be interested by http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore them. If you want to put non standard code in your website from sites like facebook and twitter you are going to have to deal with your HTML not validating.

What does that mean? Not much, the face that your site validates without the social links is a good indication that you have well structured/standard HTML and that should be the main focus of using the validator, not the gratification of getting a green "Valid!" bar.